# DNS and long running process (resolver)

Tags: dns, java, host-name-resolution

I've come across an issue where a Java (1.8) application is continuing to use the DNS servers configured when the process started rather than the current configuration. This persisted for a week before the Java application was restarted.

Specifically this is running on Centos 6 (yes, I know) with nscd (600s TTL for host caching). One of the 2 DNS servers was retired and a new one added at a different IP address. This was added to resolv.conf (i.e. 2 working DNS servers) and nscd restarted. However Java appears to continue using the retired DNS server / did not switch to the surviving DNS server / did not attempt to use the new DNS server.

Are there rules / expectations over how the resolver should behave in such a scenario?

- Should it periodically check the configuration?
- Should it try another DNS server when one times out?

Pointers to specifications (Posix?) would be appreciated

Comment: is the java code making new `getaddrinfo(3)` or whatever calls, or does it resolve only at startup?

Comment: I've long since stopped trying to make sense of how Java talks to operating systems. Unfortunately the issue only manifests on a live server which has WAY to much traffic to run call tracing against. My question is whether there are standards for how it SHOULD behave. (although the issue appears to be that it is continuing to attempt to resolve records at runtime using the DNS configuration available when the program was started).